# How to programing Encoding two RFID chip on two columns media with ZPL II

Tags: rfid, zebra-printers, zpl-ii

I used a Zebra ZT410 printer with RFID encode kit include.
I can write ZPL II code easily to encode RFID label chip on one column media.

But with the the TWO COLUMN RFID chip label media, i don't know how to encode. The RFID reader inside printer just encode the left chip only. When try to encode the right chip, it will overwrite the left one.

Please help me.

Below is failed the test code for two column:

```
^XA

^FX Set the print position of the left label
^FO0,49
^BY2^BCN,69,N,N^FD>123
^RFW,H,1,2,1^FD3400^FS
^RFW,H,2,12,1^FD496664000000000000002726^FS

^FX Set the print position of the right label
^FO423,49
^BCN,69,N,N^FD>456
^RFW,H,1,2,1^FD3400^FS
^RFW,H,2,12,1^FD496664000000000000002727^FS

^XZ
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/product-information/en-us/brochures-datasheets/rfid/transponder-guidelines/zt400-and-zt600rfid-en.pdf

Comment: Yes, i had read it, but it didn't address about two columns of inlay media.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about two columns. Are you sure this is possible at all with this printer?